# Is it possible to change font size differently according to language in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, fonts, language

I'm looking forward to a way to change font size in Emacs.

I can change easily "all" font size like this:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Consolas" :height 110)
```

But I want to change font size differently in different language.
To make Japanese a little bit smaller and Thai a little bit bigger, I wrote like this:

```
(create-fontset-from-ascii-font "Consolas" nil "my")
(set-fontset-font "fontset-my" 'japanese-jisx0208 (font-spec :family "Meiryo") nil 'append)
(set-fontset-font "fontset-my" 'thai-tis620 (font-spec :family "Cordia New") nil 'append)

(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "fontset-my"))
(setq face-font-rescale-alist '(("Meiryo" . 0.80)))
(setq face-font-rescale-alist '(("Cordia New" . 1.20)))
```

But it doesn't take effect. How can I change font size differently in different language?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to change fonts for Japanese by changing `fontset-default`:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'han "STSong-24")
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'kana "STSong-24")
```

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work; I suspect it may be because I'm specifying a script as "target" for `set-fontset-font` instead of a charset. You can see the script for a character by hitting <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>. There seems to be a `thai` script as well.

Comment: Thanks! I could make it with `(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'thai  (font-spec :family "Cordia New" :size 20))`